# c# Azure IOT Edge Auto-provision with Device Provisioning Service(DPS) with x509 certificate sample needed

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-edge

I'm new to azure IOT edge development. I'm looking for a way to Create and provision a simulated x509 certificate Edge device on Windows in c#. Is Trusted Platform Module (TPM) the only way right now with edge device?

I found this tutorial but it's for simulated TPM Edge device on Windows.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/iot-edge/how-to-auto-provision-simulated-device-windows

any idea how to do provision a device with x509 certificate? and a x509 certificate group enrollment?

Chuck

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported yet.

We just support auto-provisioning with DPS for Edge device using TPM (Sas Tokens).

It is on our radar the development for x509 provisioning, which requires modules/devices authentication with edge with x509, which is also under development.